# D3 select sibling, give it a class

Tags: jquery, select, d3.js

I have several group elements, all are siblings.

I'm trying to select the one with the class of 'sliceActive' and give it a class of 'slice' and give the next sibling down the class of 'sliceActive'

[image]

all of this will be on the click event for my next button. I know how to select the .activeSlice and give it .slice but how to I select the next g node and give it .sliceActive?

```
       $(".button").click(function(){
            d3.select("g.sliceActive").attr('class','slice');
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS adjacent sibling

```
d3.select("g.sliceActive + g").attr('class','sliceActive');
```

Might want to check browser support based on your particular requirements.

Comment: right, That gives the next g node a class of sliceActive but how do I also get rid of .sliceActive on the original g node that had it? thx

Comment: `d3.select("g.sliceActive").classed("sliceActive",false)`

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to go to the previous sibling instead of the next one? (for a previous button)

Comment: I think your original question has been answered. If the answer is acceptable, please mark it as such. If you're interested in a consulting engagement, contact me directly.

Comment: To go to the previous sibling previousNode = node.previousSibling